# The difference between Total derivatives and derivatives

Tags: derivatives

If
$f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$

$x \to x^3$

Find $df\over dx$ and $D f(x)$

solution:

${df \over dx} (x)=3x^2$

$D f(x) : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$

$h \to D f(x).h={df \over dx} (x).h=3x^2.h$

I don't understand the total derivative, why we put h?

Comment: Could you provide more context?

Comment: Your question is not about the total derivative which says that if $g(t) = f(x_1(t),\ldots,x_n(t))$ then $g'(t) = \sum_{k=1}^n x_k'(t)\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_k}(x_1(t),\ldots,x_n(t))$

Comment: Here $Df(x)$ is the differential : the linear operator such that $f(x+h)-f(x) \sim Df(x).h$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, for $\mathbf{f}:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$, the total derivative is the linear map $A:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$, such that $\lim_{\mathbf{h}\to 0}
|\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{h})-\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x})-A\mathbf{h}|/|\mathbf{h}|=0
$.
In the special case of a real valued function of one variable, $f:\mathbb{R}^1\to\mathbb{R}^1$, one can check that the linear map $A$ in the definition above is, in this case, the map $T_{f'(x)}:h\mapsto f'(x)h$, i.e., multiply $h$ by the number $f'(x)$.
Note that it is the canonical identification between the number $f'(x)$ and the linear map $T_{f'(x)}$ that allows the classical definition of the derivative and the definition of the multivariable version (the total derivative) to coincide.